# Starting JBoss via chef vagrant

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe

Im starting jboss service via chef

```
service "jboss" do 
    action :start
end
```

returns error

```
localhost Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
localhost ------------------------------------
localhost Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
localhost ---- Begin output of /sbin/service jboss start ----
localhost STDOUT: Starting JBoss AS 5.1.0
localhost STDERR: 
localhost ---- End output of /sbin/service jboss start ----
localhost Ran /sbin/service jboss start returned 1
```

but when i logged in vagrant ssh, the jboss service succcesfully run,

I think chef is failing because of the returned string by Jboss 'Starting JBoss AS 5.1.0' and service resource needs 0 here.

what am i missing? how to succesfully run this.

Comment: this has got nothing to do with either Chef itself or the output string. The issue is that `/sbin/service jboss start` return an exit code of `1`. In the shell, an exit code of `0` means success, anything else failure.
Either you have an issue in the init script (who's exiting with `1` despite a success), or JBoss was started by something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Seems the service resource checks the exit code is 0 (if success). On my jboss shell script, i placed a note that it has already started, thus, chef doesnt understand that and returns an error.

@cbl how can i put your answer to correct?